# Slatejs: How at query and update an existing node?

Tags: reactjs, slatejs

I am trying to do something like this in order to updated and already existed node, but the docs are not clear about it.

```
const paht = [0,1,1,2]
const data: any = {
                type: 'ref',
                id: uniqid(),
                data: target,
                x: 'new data are here.,',
                children: [{text: 'more new data'}],
            }

editor.apply({
                type: 'update_node_at_path',
                path:path,
                newProperties: {
                    node:data,
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.slatejs.org/api/transforms - Try passing the `NodeOptions` here, to Transforms.setNodes/anything else that suits your case.
If you have a specific path, you can pass `{at: ...}` to most node transforms